# CSS: question about lists

Tags: css

is there any way to create a table like this below using lists ?

```
**************
*  1  * 1.1  *
**************
      * 1.2  *    
      ********
      * 1.3  *    
      ********
      * 1.4  *    
      ********
```

Regards

Javi

Comment: If you need to tabulate data, then using tables is usually ideal.

Comment: Well what i want to create exactly is a form. 1 is the label. 1.1 is the field. And the rest are message errors.

Comment: So it's not actually a list either. Putting a label beside a field is relatively straightforward with `float: left` and getting errors intended is a simple matter of `margin-left`.

Comment: @VotyeDisciple: yes, but i wanted something more straightforward than giving a margin-left.

Comment: @user248959: that sounds like terrible usability. But edit the question and make clear what you have and what you want, and you're bound to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use two `<UL>`

ex:

```
<ul><li>List 1
    <ul><li>Item 1.1</li>
        <li>Item 1.2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This would show up like this :

- List 1

  - Item 1.1
  - Item 1.2

After that, you could add css class to organize it all!

Comment: I don't know, the example he gave looks like the perfect candidate for an ordered list (`ol`).

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border=1>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>1.1</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan=3></td><td>1.2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1.3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1.4</td></tr>
</table>
```